# How to convert Collection<List<Map.Entry<Long, Long>>> to List<List<Long>> using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have one function with input type Collection<List<Map.Entry<Long, Long>>> .How to convert it to
`List<List>` of keys from map using streams.

```
List<List<Long>> toMap(Collection<List<Map.Entry<Long, Long>>> input) {
return (List<List<Long>> of keys from map);}
```

How to make this conversion ??

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.stream()
   .map(
      list -> list.stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Naman: Not to satisfy the OP's specific request for a `List<List<Long>>`.  Use of `flatMap` would get a `List<Long>`.